# Invalid request google map API in android 4.4?

Tags: android, google-maps, encoding

I want to get PlaceID from location name, it working on browser and android 5.0.

```
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+namelocation+"&key=MY_KEY";
```

Result look like: [image]

But in android 4.4, I get:

```
{"results":[],"status":"INVALID_REQUEST"}
```

I try change namelocation by: `Uri.encode(namelocation)`, `URLEncoder.encode(namelocation, "utf-8");`
But it not work.

Any help, thanks!

Comment: Thank for your suggest. But that image just show for anyone know my url can working on some device.

Comment: have you tried the solution here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218312/google-maps-geocoding-invalid-request). Basically you need to add the IP Address to the list of accepted ones.

Comment: I try change namelocation by: Uri.encode(namelocation), URLEncoder.encode(namelocation, "utf-8"); But it not work.

Comment: have you found the solution? @rome웃